# Chef - Passing Attributes in an array to a template as multiple lines

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In my attributes I am trying to create server admins to be passed to a template.  However, because of how the template is read by the linux server, they need to be individual lines in the template for each admin.

How would I make this a reality by just using my attributes, and a template?

**In the Template .erb file** -

```
Admins= <%= node['game_server']['game_session']['admin1'] %>
Admins= <%= node['game_server']['game_session']['admin2'] %>
```

**My attributes file lines look like this** -

```
default['game_server']['game_session']['admin1'] = 'admin1'
default['game_server']['game_session']['admin2'] = 'admin2'
```

I want to make an Array in attributes, and have the template.erb file pull them...  Something like this would be nice in an attribute file instead of individual lines defining each admin -

**An Example of what I'd like to do (if possible) -**

```
default['game_server']['server_admins'] = {
  'admin1': { 'Admins=': 'admin1' },
  'admin2': { 'Admins=': 'admin2' },
}
```

I'm just learning Chef as an Ops person, so sorry for a noob question.  I don't know much about programming languages yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attributes:

```
default['game_server']['server_admins'] = ['admin1', 'admin2']
```

template:

```
<% node['game_server']['server_admins'].each do |admin| %>
  Admins= <%= admin %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Dude!  Thanks so much!!!  Makes sense now!  Have a fabulous evening my friend!